# Symfony 4 - Injecting constructor params into an autowired third-party service

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm using Symfony 4, and currently integrating the [Symfony Serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) component. Through autowiring, the Serializer service provided can be automatically injected into classes by typehinting a method, like so,

```
// Container injects instance of \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer

public function indexAction(SerializerInterface $serializer)
```

That third party `Serializer` class can accept an array of Normalizers and Encoders at the [point of construction](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#usage), <s>which in the default registered service are I believe empty</s> (See below).

Is there a way to trigger the injection of normalizers and encoders on creation of that service (essentially updating the configuration for that service) or does a custom service have to be registered in the application's `services.yaml` file that refers to that third party class, containing the arguments? If the latter, how would an array of Normalizer/Encoder classes be defined and injected into that service as arguments?

**Edit**

Turns out I was wrong about the default Serializer service having no encoders/normalizers (otherwise it'd be pretty useless not knowing how to do anything!), below is its default state;

[image: Default Serializer Encoders, Decoders and Normalizers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the later would be what you're looking for.

The way to implement passing those normalizers/encoders to a constructor (since these are neither scalar nor services) is to provide custom service factory class, much like this:

**[Using a Factory to Create Services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html)**

Hope this helps...

Comment: Glad I could help ;-)